# Include the 'In Folder' column in my search results MSOutlook 10?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have so many sub-subfolders that when I do a search in all folders in MS Outlook 10, I do not know in which sub-subfolder the e-mail is actually located.  How do I permanently include the 'In Folder' column in my search results?

Answer (score 0):

You may find this VBA alternative useful. It displays the folder path and offers to switch to the folder.

http://www.vboffice.net/sample.html?lang=en&mnu=2&smp=65&cmd=showitem

```
Public Sub GetItemsFolderPath()
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Msg as String
  Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
  If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
    Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
  Else
    Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
  End If
  Set F = obj.Parent
  Msg = "The path is: " & F.FolderPath & vbCrLf
  Msg = Msg & "Switch to the folder?"
  If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = F
  End If
End Sub
```

Editor and button help - http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/